# Getting random timeouts when creating Azure DevOps project with API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm implementing an API to create custom AzDo projects (my API calls the AzDo API).
About the creation:

1. Create project
2. Create two custom groups
3. Setup the permissions for the custom groups (area, iteration, build, ...)

Now my problem is that everything is working fine for one project. When creating more then one project I'm getting timeouts from AzDo, the strange thing is that I do not create all projects in the same time. I have a queue => My service always grabs one item from the queue => Means the service is creating the projects in row, not all at the same time. But it seems like that I´m getting the timeouts after I created 4 or 5 projects in a row.
If I´m waiting for some minutes between the creation, there seems to be no problems.
Note: I´m really getting the timeouts randomly, sometimes it could be a POST, another time it could be a PUT.
Does anybody have the same problem - or better, does anyone know to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Getting random timeouts when creating Azure DevOps project with API

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed** and is not a issue. There is no way to fix it at present.

In order to improve the response of Azure devops service and reduce the occupation of server by invalid requests, MS gives restrictions on REST API requests:

- Only have one REST API task active at a given point in an account.
- Set Api Response had a 20 second timeout.

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167643/vsts-build-more-than-one-rest-api-task-cant-be-run.html) and [similar document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination) for some more details.

Currently, there is no better way to modify the default timeout period, you could try to reduce the number of projects you create at once.

Comment: Thx for that answer @Leo Liu! 
But one more question: That also means that I shouldn´t start more than one API Call - so no async calls?
Actually in my case what I´m doing async is to set the permissions => so should be sync?

Comment: @Chrizzo, You could start more than one API Call, But in fact, the access to the service is not simultaneous.